# Problema con pip en CMD

Tags: python, cmd, pip

Buen día, cada vez que intento usar **pip** en **CMD** me sale lo siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\archivos de programa\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "d:\archivos de programa\python\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Archivos de programa\Python\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Me es raro ya que lo usaba mucho, empezó a fallar desde hace unos días que intenté actualizarlo, ya reinstalé python y sigue igual, verifiqué las variables del entorno y todo está aparentemente bien.

¿Alguien sabrá como arreglarlo?

Comment: ¿Revisaste si la ruta de donde se encuentra el archivo *pip.exe* es correcto y coincide con la que tienes configurada en tus variables de entorno?

Comment: ¿Qué sale al teclear ``pip -V``? Si no sale nada, deberás reinstalar **pip**. Abre una terminal y teclea: ``python get-pip.py``

Answer (score 0):

Hay que comprobar si `pip` está ahí. Si alguno de estos comandos falla:

```
python -m pip --version
pip --version
```

Debes reinstalar Pip. Quizás Windows no permitió que el módulo se reinstalara (Windows no suele dejar que los programas modifiquen a otros programas, y puede dejar la reinstalación incompleta). Hay varios métodos para reinstalar Pip. Puedes usar [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#get-pip-py) o el módulo estándar [`ensurepip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#ensurepip). También sería prudente darle privilegios administrativos a tu terminal.

Si nada de esto funciona, quizá tengas que reinstalar Python, y agregar Python a la variable de entorno PATH (En el instalador de [CPython](https://python.org/downloads/windows) para Windows, te pregunta antes de instalar).

Answer (score 0):

Intenta actualizar pip y también tu versión de python. Usa los comandos anteriormente mencionados para instalar pip, también mira el traceback e intenta hacer un debugg.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/301834)